# Complex operation with bash script

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I got a document with several lines, some of them contains the string below, what I need to do is display all the other lines (that already has been filtered by grep), and whenever this string appears multiply the number by 2500 and display the result in the same column.

*-other columns-* is just a place holder to demonstrate that other columns exists after and before: value=All 968.0

```
-other columns-  value=All 968.0 -other columns-
```

Is this posible?

I have tried the folowing but it returns only the column with the math operation, and do the operation in all lines, I want the operation only in the rows that contains "value=All" in the sixth column.

```
grep wordFilter file.txt | sed -e 's/wordsToDelete//g' | if grep -q value=All ; then awk '{print $7*2500}' ; fi
```

this is the important part:

```
 if grep -q value=All ; then awk '{print $7*2500}' ; fi
```

Comment: Of course it's possible. It would be easiest to do it in `awk`.

Comment: We encourage all users on SO to post their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problem, so kindly do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Answer (score 0):

The code is using grep/awk pipe to perform the filtering. However, `grep -q` will consume all output from the pipe, and no data will go into the `awk`. Consider

```
# Print just lines with value=A::
grep wordFilter file.txt | sed -e 's/wordsToDelete//g' | awk '/value=ALL/ {$4 = $4*2500 ; print }'

# Or print all lines
grep wordFilter file.txt | sed -e 's/wordsToDelete//g' | awk '/value=ALL/ {$4 = $4*2500 } { print }'
```

Based on sample input, looks like the value is in the 4th column, therefore $4 instead of $7

Comment: Hi, thanks, but this return only the lines that contains "value=All" I also need the other lines that not contains the string.

Comment: Can you try the second command (with 'print all lines')  - it should include the 'other lines'  in the output